# Vue.js - How do I display row specific data using vuetify data table via icon click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify data table that displays order data. The last column in each row is an icon the user can click to cancel their order. When the user clicks the cancel icon, they are prompted with a confirm cancel order overlay that displays the `order id`.

The problem I am having is when my overlay opens, the `order_id` does not update based on the row I click. It appears to be displaying the first `order_id` in my items array I am displaying in the data table.

I am using a unique `itemKey` for each row in the data table.

What am I doing wrong that is preventing me from displaying row specific data for each order?

```
<v-data-table
  v-if="orders.length > 0"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="orders"
  multi-sort
  :search="search"
  class="elevation-1"
 >
<template v-slot:[`item.length`]="{ item }">
 <span>{{item.length | transform}}</span>
</template>
<template v-slot:[`item.weight`]="{ item }">
 <span>{{item.weight | transform}}</span>
</template>
<template  v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
 <v-icon small @click="cancelOverlay = true" color="red">mdi-cancel</v-icon>
 <v-overlay v-if="cancelOverlay">
  <v-card light color="#f6f9fc" max-width="1000px">
   <v-card-title primary-title>
    <div>
     <span class="display-1 mb-0 black--text">Are you sure you want to cancel order #{{item.order_id}}?</span>
    </div>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn icon dark color="black" @click="cancelOverlay = false">
     <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
   </v-card-title>
   <v-container>
    <CancelOrderComponent :orderId="item.order_id" />
   </v-container>
  </v-card>
 </v-overlay>
</template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: which click do you mean?

Comment: the cancel icon in each row. the rows themselves are not selectable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CancelOrderComponent` should be outside the `v-data-table` component and add another data property named `currentOrderId` and update it using that click event `@click="cancelOverlay = true; currentOrderId=item.order_id;"` and reset it like `@click="cancelOverlay = false; currentOrderId=-1;"`:

```
<v-data-table
....
<template  v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
 <v-icon small @click="cancelOverlay = true; currentOrder=item;" color="red">mdi-cancel</v-icon>
 <v-overlay v-if="cancelOverlay">
  <v-card light color="#f6f9fc" max-width="1000px">
   <v-card-title primary-title>
    <div>
     <span class="display-1 mb-0 black--text">Are you sure you want to cancel order #{{currentOrder.order_id}}?</span>
    </div>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn icon dark color="black" `@click="cancelOverlay = false; currentOrder=null;"`>
     <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
   </v-card-title>
    <v-container>
    <CancelOrderComponent :orderId="currentOrder.order_id" />
   </v-container>
  </v-card>
 </v-overlay>
</template>
</v-data-table>
 
...
```

script :

```
data(){
  return{
    currentOrder: null,
   }

}
```

Comment: that's not quite what I want. I still want the cancel order component to only show when the cancel icon is clicked. Your solution still lead me to solving my issue. I've edited your answer with what worked for me

Comment: i approved your edit , i just gave a first solution and i have been waiting for your feedback  in order to improve it